# Solving an implicit equation involving Elliptic integral

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions

I have the following equation:

```
EllipticE[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] + 
  16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2*EllipticK[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] == 0
```

I want to find values of `me` and `mo`. I have tried to find these by using `Solve` and `FindRoot` but I didn't get anything. Is there any other way to solve it? And how do I plot `mo` or `me` as a function of `ja` and `jb`?

Comment: What I see is $E(1/(1+k^2)) + k^2 K(1/(1+k^2 ) >1 k real ? 

For k^2 -> -k^2  

FindRoot[
 EllipticE[1/(1 - k^2)] - k^2*EllipticK[1/(1 - k^2)], {k, 1.3}]   -> {k -> 1.29066}

Comment: Please include the code you have tried with `Solve` and `FindRoot`. It's likely that an analytical solution might not be available, but it should be possible to find one numerically, if one exists. Have you tried some plotting to just get an idea of a good starting guess for root finding?

Comment: I was thinking to plot it but here we have two unknown param $mo$ and $me$ so should I freeze one of the param (let's say put $mo=0$) and then 3DPlot $me$ as a function of $ja$ and $jb$, right??

Comment: Replace `(ja*me + jb*mo)` with `u` and `Plot[EllipticE[1/(1+16*u^2)]+16*u^2*EllipticK[1/(1+16*u^2)],{u,-1,1}]`

Comment: @Bill that plot does not cross through x axis which implies no root exists?!

Comment: @Barry For Real values of ja,me,jb,mo you appear to be correct, I haven't tried Complex values. BUT you have to check everything I do several different ways before you trust that I haven't made some mistake. When `Reduce` and `Solve` and `FindRoot` can't find something I try things like `Plot` and variations of `Minimize` to see if I can convince myself there is no root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = EllipticE[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] + 
    16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2*EllipticK[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] == 0;
```

As recommended by @Bill,

```
eq2 = eq1 /. ja*me + jb*mo :> u

(* EllipticE[1/(1 + 16 u^2)] + 16 u^2 EllipticK[1/(1 + 16 u^2)] == 0 *)

FindInstance[eq2, u, Reals]

(* FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient 
  to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. *)
```

Removing the domain constraint,

```
(sol = FindInstance[eq2, u, 2]) // N

(* {{u -> 0. - 0.322665 I}, {u -> 0. + 0.322665 I}} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eq2 /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

Graphically,

```
ComplexPlot3D[eq2[[1]], {u, -1 - I, 1 + I},
 AxesLabel -> {Re, Im, None}]
```

[image]

```
eq3 = eq2 /. u -> I*y

(* EllipticE[1/(1 - 16 y^2)] - 16 y^2 EllipticK[1/(1 - 16 y^2)] == 0 *)

FindRoot[eq3, {y, #}] & /@ {-0.3, 0.3}

(* {{y -> -0.322665}, {y -> 0.322665}} *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[Evaluate@eq3[[1]], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be reduced to a (complex) quadratic equation in four variables. One may obtain one variable in terms of the other three, but one may **not** obtain **two** of the variables in terms of the other two, as requested by the OP.

```
eqn = EllipticE[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] + 
    16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2*EllipticK[1/(1 + 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2)] == 0;

(* reduction to a quadratic equation *)
ueqn = eqn /. First@Solve[u == 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2, ja] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  EllipticE[1/(1 + u)] + u EllipticK[1/(1 + u)] == 0  *)
> ```

```
usol = Solve[ueqn && -2 < u < -1, u]
eqn2 = Replace[
  usol, {{r_Rule}} :> (Equal @@ r /. 
     First@Solve[u == 16*(ja*me + jb*mo)^2, u])]
```

> ```
> (* 
> {{u -> Root[{EllipticE[1/(1 + #1)] + 
>        EllipticK[1/(1 + #1)] #1 &, -1.665807876436924963209380412862432}]}}
>
> (* quadratic equation *)
> 16 (ja me + jb mo)^2 == 
>  Root[{EllipticE[1/(1 + #1)] + 
>      EllipticK[1/(1 + #1)] #1 &, -1.665807876436924963209380412862432}]
> *)
> ```

Note the exact `Root[]` object is negative, which means the solutions are complex.  The solution space is a three-dimensional complex manifold (six real dimensions) in four-dimensional complex space (eight real dimensions). I don't know how one would graphically represent such a solution space, but algebraically, it is not hard to deal with.

#### Numerical/graphical evidence of only one solution

One solution to `ueqn` inside `Abs[u] <= 2.5`:

```
Show[
 ComplexPlot3D[EllipticE[1/(1 + u)] + u EllipticK[1/(1 + u)],
  {u, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I},
  ColorFunction -> {ColorData["Rainbow"][Clip[#7/4]] &, None}
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  MeshFunctions -> {Re[#1] & , Im[#1] & , Abs[#1] &}
  , Mesh -> {{0, -1, -2}, {0}, {2.5}}
  , MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Thick},
  PlotRange -> {0, 10}],
 ComplexPlot3D[0, {u, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I},
  ColorFunction -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.75, 1., 0.5] &, None}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  MeshFunctions -> {Re[#1] & , Im[#2] & }, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
 ]
```

[image]
    
No solutions outside `Abs[u]  5/u`):

```
ComplexPlot3D[EllipticE[1/(1 + 5/u)] + 5/u EllipticK[1/(1 + 5/u)],
 {u, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I},
 ColorFunction -> {ColorData["Rainbow"][Clip[#7/4]] &, None}
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 MeshFunctions -> {Re[5/#1] & , Im[5/#1] & , Abs[5/#1] &}
 , Mesh -> {{0, -1, -2}, {0}, {2.5}}
 , MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Thick}]
```

[image]

It is probably not hard to prove that there are no other solutions,
but I'll leave that to others.
For instance,
`EllipticE[1/(1 + u)]` and `EllipticK[1/(1 + u)]` are bounded for `u` sufficiently large, of course. In fact, `EllipticE[1/(1 + 5/u)] + 5/u EllipticK[1/(1 + 5/u)` is asymptotic to `(Pi/2) u`, so there are no zeros for large `u`.